# conditional compilation flags in make

Tags: c, makefile

How to solve the following problem with `make`?

```
SRCS1 = a.c b,c
SRCS2 = d.c e.c
SRCS= $(SRCS1) $(SRCS2)
OBJS1 = $(subst .c,.o,$(SRCS1))
OBJS2 = $(subst .c,.o,$(SRCS2))
OBJS = $(OBJS1) $(OBJS2)
include ../Makeconf
```

(which contains `CPPFLAGS=-Dfoo`) (the main Makefile is also in ../)
Now I want to compile `SRCS1` with `foo` defined and `SRCS2` with `foo` not defined.
I tried

```
ifneq (,$(findstring $(OBJS2),$(OBJS)))
CPPFLAGS += -Ufoo
endif
```

but that adds `-Ufoo` to all files when compiled. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the comma in the line `SRCS1 = a.c b,c` a typo?

Comment: And where is that `ifneq` statement in the makefile.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown us enough of the makefile(s) to give a complete answer, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$(OBJS2): CPPFLAGS += -Ufoo
```